# Counting primes $\pi \equiv 1(9)$ in a ray class field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am working on the imaginary quadratic field $K=\mathbb{Q} (w)$ where $w = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}$. I need to find the density of primes $\pi \equiv 1 (9)$ in ray class field $J_K^m / P_K^m$ (so I will take m=9). I want to use a refined version of generalized Chebotarev Density Theorem and to do this, I need a relation between the Galois group $G(K^m/K)$ and the ray class group $J_K^m/P_K^m$. In Neukirch's algebraic number theory book, Theorem 7.1 gives that there exists a surjective homomorphism $ CL_K^m = J_K^m/P_K^m \rightarrow G(L/K)$ for an abelian extension $L/K$ with kernel $(N_{L/K}J_L^m)P_K^m$.

Before this, (below definition 6.2) it is stated that the Galois group of the ray class field is canonically isomorphic to the
ray class group $\mod m$, so $G(K^m/K) \cong C_K/ C_K^m $. Also we have an isomorphism $C_K/C_K^m \cong CL_K^m$ (by Proposition 1.9). Then what I understand is that the surjective homomorphism of Theorem 7.1  $ CL_K^m = J_K^m/P_K^m \rightarrow G(L/K)$ has to be a an isomorphism when we take $L=K^m$ so that its kernel has to be trivial, namely, it has to be $P_K^m$. So in this case $(N_{L/K}J_L^m)$ has to be $1$. Since this is an isomorphism, the size of $P_K^m$ equals to the size of the identity automorphism of G(L/K). In this way I catch those primes $\pi \equiv 1 (9)$ since those are the elements in $P_K^m$ by definition. I am wondering whether what I understand is correct up to now. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: In fact it is the opposite, Chebotarev is proven by first proving the PNT for Hecke L-functions, then using class field theory and Brauer's theorem on induced characters to relate Artin L-functions to Hecke L-functions. Here you'll consider $L(s,\psi)$ where $\psi\in Hom(J_K^m / P_K^m,\Bbb{C}^\times)$, ie. $L(s,\psi) = \frac16\sum_{a,b\in \Bbb{Z}^2-(0,0)} \psi(a+bw) |a+bw|^{-2s}$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Perhaps I could not ask what I was trying to ask. Let me rephrase it: Is it true that the number of prime ideals $(\pi)$ where $\pi \equiv 1(9)$ and $N(\pi) \equiv x$ is asymptotic to $1/h_(9) Li(x)$, where $h_(9)$ is the order of the ray class group modulo $9$? I know one can obtain this using ray class characters modulo 9 and Perron's formula but is it possible to directly get this using Chebotarev?

Comment: Here $J^{(9)}/P^{(9)}$ is $\cong O_K/(9)^\times / O_K^\times$ which has $9$ elements. Class field theory: the Artin map gives an isomorphism to the Galois group of some abelian extension. Applying Chebotarev gives that the density of prime ideals $\equiv a \bmod (9)$ is $1/9$ for any $a\in O_K/(9)^\times$.

Comment: So $\sum_{\mathfrak{p} \ prime, N(\mathfrak{p})\le x, \exists \pi, \mathfrak{p} = (\pi), \pi-a\in 9 \Bbb{Z}[w]} 1 \sim \frac19 Li(x)$.

Comment: Dont we have $\phi(9) = 2*3^3 = 54$ elements in $(O_K/ 9O_K)^*$?

Comment: Yes but need to quotient by (the image of) $O_K^\times = \langle \zeta_6\rangle$ because we are considering principal ideals of $O_K$ not elements of $O_K$ (principal because $O_K$ is a PID, it would be more complicated with $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$)

Comment: In our case, what I understood from Neukirch' theorem is that the Artin map gives an isomorphism from $J_K^(9) / P_K^)(9)$ to Gal$(K^(9)/K)$, where $K^(9)$ is the ray class field, and picking the identity map gives what we want.